# Falha de execução no Android Studio (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.)

Tags: android, android-studio

Na execução do meu projeto está ocorrendo o erro abaixo e já pesquisei em diversos lugares, mas nenhuma solucionou para o meu problema. Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

Já reiniciei o Android Studio e dei um Clean, mas nada funcionou.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

***build.gradle ( app):***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.junior.fireflyapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
     compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

**build.gradle ( project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, edite a pergunta e coloque nela o código, recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mauricio Junior, você poderia anexar a sua pergunta o código do seu `build.gradle (app)` e `build.gradle (project)`? Provavelmente há um erro em algum desses arquivos.

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema há alguns dias. Na verdade, vi muita gente com esse erro, e dependendo da situação resolvem de formas diferentes(clean e build do projeto, redefinindo o caminho e versão do JDK, reiniciando o Android Studio), porém nenhum desses funcionou para mim. Uma opção que não pude testar ainda e deixo de dica é reinstalar o JDK, é uma das opções que vi que para algumas pessoas resolveu, porém não posso testar esta no momento. Se testar essa solução e funcionar, me avise para que eu poste como resposta correta para sua pergunta.

Comment: Já tentou dar um BUILD > REBUILD

Comment: Você já atualizou o gradle do seu Android Studio?

Comment: @WyllianNeo essa questão de reinstalar o JDK tbm não testei, assim que possível realizarei os teste e posto o resultado.

Comment: @regmoraes postei o codigo dos meus arquivos gradle.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar sobre qual o motivo desse erro? Já tentei sugestões do pessoal que mandou aqui, mas não deu em nada.

Comment: O erro era causado por essa linha:

compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'

Removi ela e o projeto do meu app funcionou, mas não é necessário essa linha para o app fazer conexão com meu banco de dados? Alguém saberia me dizer o pq ela cusava o erro?